# On page reload Hide function ignores Checked input, only works on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using JQuery to hide addition inputs based on if a check box is loaded. they're are six of them, so I used a function that will work for all of them (even though their ID's are unique.)
It works fine when they are first selected but when I select one of the Shown options (after click) the page reloads with additional data. During this reload the php checks for a "checked" box and adds the html to declare it checked. However the .js doesn't see this and still hides the child data, unless I uncheck the box and recheck it.

I tried a document load to look for it, and to move the check part of the function outside the check event.

```
<script>
$(function() {

  $('.hidden').hide();

  $('.trigger').change(function() {  
    var hiddenId = $(this).attr("data-trigger");

    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $("#" + hiddenId).show();
    } else {
      $("#" + hiddenId).hide();
    }

  });
});
</script>
```

```
<html>
<div class="boxed show1">
    <h3>Strategy Choices</h3>
    <input type="checkbox" name="repeatFromLastGame" value="1" checked="checked" data-trigger="hidden_fields_one" class="trigger"> Repeat Numbers from last Game?<br>
    <div id="hidden_fields_one" class="hidden" style="display: none;">
        <label for="numberRepeats">Number of Repeats from last game to use?</label><br>
        <select name="numberRepeats">
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1" selected="">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
        </select>
    </div><br>
    <label for="chit1">Repeat 1</label><br>
    <select name="chit1">
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="38" selected="selected">38</option>
        <option value="43">43</option>
        <option value="52">52</option>
        <option value="55">55</option>
    </select>
</div>
</html>
```

I am wanting this to see if the check box is checked first then hide it if not.

Comment: Use localstorage to store the chosen result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  // listen for trigger changes
  $('.trigger').change(function() {  
    updateView();
  });

  // on page load checks the trigger value and updates the view
  updateView();
  
});

function updateView(){
  var hiddenId = $('.trigger').attr("data-trigger");

  if ($('.trigger').is(':checked')) {
    $("#" + hiddenId).show();
  } else {
    $("#" + hiddenId).hide();
  }
}
```

```css
.hidden{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<div class="boxed show1">
 <h3>Strategy Choices</h3>
 <input type="checkbox" name="repeatFromLastGame" value="1" checked="checked" data-trigger="hidden_fields_one" class="trigger"> Repeat Numbers from last Game?<br>
 <div id="hidden_fields_one" class="hidden" style="display: none;">
  <label for="numberRepeats">Number of Repeats from last game to use?</label><br>
  <select name="numberRepeats">
   <option value="0">0</option>
   <option value="1" selected="">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
   <option value="5">5</option>
  </select>
 </div><br>
 <label for="chit1">Repeat 1</label><br>
 <select name="chit1">
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="38" selected="selected">38</option>
  <option value="43">43</option>
  <option value="52">52</option>
  <option value="55">55</option>
 </select>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: This absolutely did it! Thanks!
Can you explain What is happening with your change?

Comment: In your code you are listening for the trigger changes. But it does not check the trigger value on page load. So until you click the trigger nothing happens.

Comment: So in `function updateView(){
  var hiddenId = $('.trigger').attr("data-trigger");

  if ($('.trigger').is(':checked')) {
    $("#" + hiddenId).show();
  } else {
    $("#" + hiddenId).hide();
  }
}`
the ` var hiddenId = $('.trigger').attr("data-trigger");`
is "hidden_fields_one" , correct?

Comment: If this is true shouldn't this jquery also work if I created a second set exactly as the first but rename data-trigger and the corresponding div id like so;
`<input type="checkbox" name="newName" value="1" checked="checked" data-trigger="hidden_fields_two" class="trigger"> Text for new checkBox?<br>
 <div id="hidden_fields_two" class="hidden" style="display: none;">
  <label for="SelectNameTwo">Text for second option?</label><br>
  <select name="SelectNameTwo">
   <option value="0">0</option>
   <option value="1">1</option>
  </select>
 </div>`

Comment: This was my intention to create one function driving each checkbox and corresponding div to hide/show. Where is this failing?

Comment: Provide a fiddle whenever you can. Your code is not clear and hard to understand